# Rails 5.1: issue to sending parameter to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, coffeescript

I am making a method for the users can see the perfil of each user and follow, I use CoffeScript to handle a button and build a JSON file that contains the friend_id to follow and sending with a POST request to the UsersController, after that, sending by parameters to the Users model for create a row in the datebase.

app.js.coffe:

```
$ = jQuery

$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $('#follow_btn').on "click", ->
      friend = $(this).data("friend")
      boton = $(this)
      $.ajax "/usuario/follow", 
      type: "POST"
      dataType: "JSON"
      data: {usuario: { friend_id: friend }}
      success: (data)->
        console.log data
        boton.slideUp()
        alert friend
      error: (err)->
        console.log err
        alert "No hemos podido crear la amistad"
```

User Controller

```
class UsuarioController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def show
     @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
  end

  def follow
    respond_to do |format|
        if current_usuario.follow!(post_params)
            format.json {head :no_content}
        else
            format.json {render json: "Se encontraron errores"}
        end
     end
  end

  private
  def post_params
     params.require(:usuario).permit(:friend_id)
  end
end
```

I think that the problem is here when execute **current_usuario.follow!(post_params)**

is not sending the friend_id

```
def follow!(amigo_id)
  friendships.create(friend_id = amigo_id)
end
```

the row is created, but the field friend_id is getting Nil

I try with pass the friend_id directly like this:

```
current_usuario.follow!(3)
```

that way the field friend_id saved properly

the model user.

```
class Usuario < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook, :twitter]

  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships

  has_many :follows, through: :friendships, source: :friend

  has_many :followers_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", 
  foreign_key: "friend_id"

  has_many :followers, through: :followers_friendships, source: 
  :usuario

  def follow!(amigo_id)
    friendships.create!(friend_id: amigo_id)
  end

  def can_follow?(amigo_id)
    not amigo_id == self.id or friendships.where(friend_id: 
    amigo_id).size > 0
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, 
  length: {in:5..20, too_short: "Al menos 5 caracteres", too_long: 
  "Maximo 20 caracteres"}

  def self.find_or_create_by_omniauth(auth)
    usuario = self.find_or_create_by(provider: auth[:provider], uid: 
    auth[:uid]) do |user|
        user.nombre = auth[:name]
        user.apellido = auth[:last_name]
        user.username = auth[:username]
        user.email = auth[:email]
        user.uid = auth[:uid]
        user.provider = auth[:provider]
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: are you sure friend_id is getting in `friend = $(this).data("friend")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `follow!` expects the `id` (a number, assuming `Friend` model follows rails defaults) as a parameter, but you are passing the compelte `post_params` hash in this line:

```
if current_usuario.follow!(post_params)
```

If you inspect the value of `post_params` you will see it is a hash, something like this:

```
{ friend_id: 3 }
```

But you only want to pass `3`; so, to solve this, just pass `friend_id` value (i.e. `post_params[:friend_id]`) instead:

```
if current_usuario.follow!(post_params[:friend_id])
```

Or:

```
if current_usuario.follow!(params[:usuario][:friend_id])
```